# In Moderncv, add a footnote to a cventry

Tags: moderncv, footmisc

In a resume created using the Moderncv template, I've been able to add footnotes to 'regular' text by adding the line

`\usepackage{footmisc}`

and subsequently using \footnotemark and \footnotetext{} at the bottom of the page, as suggested in previous posts. However, if I try to add a footnotemark in a cventry:

```
\cventry{2012--Present}{Quantitative Interpretation (QI) geophysicist}{NAM B.V\footnotemark}{}{}{Contribute to increasing the success rate of exploration and development drilling by screening prospects for direct hydrocarbon indicators (DHIs).}
```

then I get the following error:

```
! Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition.
```

`\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}`

```
\def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
```

Does anyone know why the \footnotemark doesn't work in a cventry?

Comment: `\protect\footnotemark` seems to work, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/106162